# createCriteria methods in spring hibernate integration application

Tags: spring, hibernate-criteria

I am working on basic spring and hibernate application.  I am using createCriteria() methods for retrieving data from database.  But I have removed transaction methods (like beginTransaction() or commit).  Is it possible to use criteriaQueries without transaction methods? 
I understand that I can achieve this using spring transaction.  But I want to do it in Hibernate.  Can anyone clarify this for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Removing this method call is a good thing because Spring can do it for you and it avoid the mixing of concern problem.

The annotation @Transactional around a method automaticaly start and commit (or revert on Exception) a transaction. That is what your are supposed to use.

But Spring is not 100% magic to make the @Transactionnal annotation to work you will have to declare a transaction Manager. And use it in Spring component (@Component,@Repository,@Bean,...) and on non private method.

Exemple in a spring 3 project using hibernate 3

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

there is also a Transaction manager for hibernate 4, and with spring 4 you can declare it in code with @EnableTransactionManagement if you dont use xml.

Note : that if you annotate your class with @Repository every method will be transactional.

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html